# How to get Customer's Order using Magento 2 Rest API?

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, rest-api

I want to know is there any `REST API` available to get customer's Order in Magento 2?

Comment: Let me know if you have still any query ?

Answer (score 6):

To get customer's Order using REST API **try below code :**

First you need to get accesstoken of **admin** and then needs to call order api with passing that **AccessToken**.

**Code for get admin accesstoken :**

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$ch = curl_init("http://yourwebsiteurl/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Code for get order details :**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://yourwebsiteurl/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

here is the link for all the rest api available in magento 2  - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

Comment: @Dipak Valecha Let me know if you have still any query ?

Comment: If there is any way to use customer token without admin token. It is not security wise.

Comment: As a part of security , if you want to use customer token then you can get only specific customer order data not all data . example - if you create token of X customer then you can get only that X customer data

Comment: yes I tried that for a specific user  ex. `https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=aaa@gmail.com`.  but to run this I must use admin token not customer. Do you have any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use orders endpoint with filter on customer id

```
{{magentoDomain}}/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]={{customerId}}&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an admin token you need to have the credentials setup within magento and call /V1/integration/admin/token endpoint with the username/password and get the token. Then pass the token to other requests with Authorization: Bearer